# Call Method JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm programming in Java using JNI.
I've configured all through NetBeans.

When a Java Method is called inside a C Method, the result obtained is shown before other operations inside the same C method. I attach some code.

Here the C code, called twice inside main:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnidemojava_Main_myprint
 (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){ 

 jfieldID fldid;
 jint nx, nnx;

  (void)printf("Hello from a Native Method\n");

  if (obj == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Input pointer is null!\n");
    return;
  }
  if ((fldid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,
        (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj), "x", "I")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetFieldID failed");
    return;
  }

  nx = (*env)->GetIntField(env, obj, fldid);/* retrieve myNumber */
  printf("\"myNumber\" value is %d\n", nx);

  (*env)->SetIntField(env, obj, fldid, ++nx);/* increment it! */
  nnx = (*env)->GetIntField(env, obj, fldid);

  printf("\"myNumber\" value now %d\n", nnx); /* make sure */

  if(nnx==10){
      //richiama un metodo di Main

      //jclass myClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "Main");
      jclass myClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
      jmethodID myMethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, myClass, "method", "(I)V");
      int c=100;
      (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, obj, myMethod,c);
      printf("CALLED!");
  }
```

Here the java method called by C:

```
public void method(int c) throws InterruptedException{
    System.out.println("Method called from C "+c);
}
```

All is ok, but i don't understand why the output order is wrong.

OUTPUT

```
Method called from C 100
"myNumber" value is 8
"myNumber" value now 9
"myNumber" value is 9
"myNumber" value now 10
CALLED!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the printf method/or stdout have an internal buffer. If you need the correct order you can flush stdout: `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: You are right!
Thank you Robert!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNI system.out and printf behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085044/jni-system-out-and-printf-behaviour)